# Sending an HttpWebRequest to an HTTPS REST service

Tags: c#, json, ssl, curl

I'm trying to send a JSON request to a REST service that is HTTPS secured. The client explained that the REST service is using self-signed certificates. He also explained that this is a development service and that I should ignore any certificate warnings. (The service is running on a RaspberryPi in our office)

He forwarded me the following CURL request to demonstrate that it's working:

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"MerchantReference":"[removed]",
     "Command":"Debit", "Amount":5500,"DeviceSerialNumber":"[removed]"}'  https://[removed]
```

When I establish a connection with Putty and run this, I get a response so all is good. But when I write an app in C# to do this, I get the following exception:
"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send." The inner exception is: "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream."

Here is my C# code:

```
var tempRequest = @"{""MerchantReference"":""[removed]"",""Command"":""Debit"",
                                    ""Amount"":5500,""DeviceSerialNumber"":""[removed]""}";

HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(HttpAddress) as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tempRequest);
Stream postData = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
postData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
postData.Close();

var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse(); // The exception occurred here
```

I have added a callback to ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback at the start of the application to just accept any certificate but the execution doesn't even reach that part.

So my question would be how to replicate the CURL result in C#.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. TLS v1.2 is used and we are using .Net 4.0 which only supports up to TLS V1.0. We'll either upgrade to .Net 4.5 or use a different version of TLS.

Comment: You can use TLS 1.2 also un .NET 4, with this command ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;